# Sidebar opens and closes on every page load

Tags: magento2.4

This is the website

https://roadmarket.sa/

On mobile, the sidebar opens and closes on every page load.

The issue only comes in Arabic locale/storeview, so I tried to remove all custom themes and made only one theme for Arabic with parent Magento/blank. But still the issue persists.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following things.

1. Initial make the bar as "Display:none".
2. When page load is complete, make that as "Dsiplay:block".